# Identification of active network card and get Default Gateway

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

How do I get the identification of the active network card and get the default gateway?

[image: http://s4.picofile.com/file/7871762682/Default_Gateway.png]

Comment: What do you mean by indentification of active network card?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634868/get-the-default-gateway

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457119/how-to-get-default-nic-connection-name

Answer (score 3):

The following code gives you the first Default Gateway:

```
 NetworkInterface card = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault();
 if (card == null)
    return null;
 GatewayIPAddressInformation address = card.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.FirstOrDefault();
 if (address == null)
     return null;

 return address.Address;
```

Comment: what does it mean by first default gateway?

Comment: In the windows TCP/IP 4 Properties you can press the "Advanced" button. Then you can add multiple "Default gateway's".